# Is there a text only desktop enviornment for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

This is more of a Linux question, but I was wondering if there is a text based desktop environment. I need something I can use over SSH.

Comment: Something other than the shell?

Comment: The shell is great, but sometimes it can get old. I want something that looks nice.

Comment: Maybe it's not something you would call a true "desktop environment", but Midnight Commander does a great job for me.

Comment: What's wrong with the -X or -Y when you invoke ssh?  That way you can just run any X program (assuming you are starting from a machine with X installed and have allowed access with xhost +...).

Comment: @raj, yeah I use MC, and really like it. ubfan1, I don't know how to use ssh graphically. Can you post a tutorial?

Comment: Update: Yeah, I realized how to do it pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

? why not better to uninstall all gui environments? then you'll automatically have gui. and my second way is to setup grub to always open recovery mode and not gui (then you have pure cli). and if you want just a really tine environment i found something and that's there : https://reposhub.com/linux/miscellaneous/netxs-group-VTM.html (yes it's in CLI)